# Error when setting batchnoem layers to frozen under mps device on a m1 mac

Tags: macos, deep-learning, pytorch, mps

I have been struggling with this weird error for a few days now and I can’t seem to find a solution, the code I provide works perfectly when using cpu but when using the mps device on a mbp 14 it throws an error. Additionally it definitely is not a memory issue as the code runs if all params are set to trainable it breaks only when batchnorm are frozen and everything else isn’t

````
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim
from torchvision.models.resnet import resnet50, ResNet50_Weights

model = resnet50(weights=ResNet50_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V1)
for name, param in model.named_parameters():
    if "bn" in name or "batchnorm" in name.lower():
        param.requires_grad = False
        
# Adding a custom classification head
num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
model.fc = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Dropout(0.2),
    nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 1024),
    nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
    nn.Dropout(0.2),
    nn.Linear(1024, 512),
    nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
    nn.Dropout(0.2),
    nn.Linear(512, 3),
)

# Then I have a standard training loop stored in a class
  trainer = ModelTrainer(model, train_loader, val_loader, num_epochs=1)
  model = trainer.train()
  history = trainer.history()```


And here is the Error:
````

Error:

### Using mps device
Epoch 1/1

train:   0%|                                                                           | 0/38 [00:00<?, ? batch/s]2023-04-07 17:41:27.555 python[8858:237219] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKeyedSubscript:]: key cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b2a78418 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001b25c2ea8 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b2b5dcc4 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1 + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b2b6ae4c -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKeyedSubscript:].cold.2 + 0
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001b29c5a0c -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKeyedSubscript:] + 928
5   libtorch_cpu.dylib                  0x0000000157ecd280 _ZN2at6native23batch_norm_backward_mpsERKNS_6TensorES3_RKN3c108optionalIS1_EES8_S8_S8_S8_bdNSt3__15arrayIbLm3EEE + 4380
6   libtorch_cpu.dylib                  0x000000015463284c _ZN2at4_ops26native_batch_norm_backward10redispatchEN3c1014DispatchKeySetERKNS_6TensorES6_RKNS2_8optionalIS4_EESA_SA_SA_SA_bdNSt3__15arrayIbLm3EEE + 200
7   libtorch_cpu.dylib                  0x00000001563d99b4 *ZN3c104impl28wrap_kernel_functor_unboxed_INS0_6detail24WrapFunctionIntoFunctor_INS_26CompileTimeFunctionPointerIFNSt3__15tupleIJN2at6TensorES8_S8_EEENS_14DispatchKeySetERKS8_SC_RKNS_8optionalIS8_EESG_SG_SG_SG_bdNS5_5arrayIbLm3EEEEXadL_ZN5torch8autograd12VariableType12_GLOBAL__N_126native_batch_norm_backwardESA_SC_SC_SG_SG_SG_SG_SG_bdSI_EEEES9_NS_4guts8typelist8typelistIJSA_SC_SC_SG_SG_SG_SG_SG_bdSI_EEEEESJ_E4callEPNS_14OperatorKernelESA_SC_SC_SG_SG_SG_SG_SG_bdSI* + 2392
8   libtorch_cpu.dylib                  0x00000001546324ec _ZN2at4_ops26native_batch_norm_backward4callERKNS_6TensorES4_RKN3c108optionalIS2_EES9_S9_S9_S9_bdNSt3__15arrayIbLm3EEE + 468
9   libtorch_cpu.dylib                  0x00000001560bcce8 _ZN5torch8autograd9generated24NativeBatchNormBackward05applyEONSt3__16vectorIN2at6TensorENS3_9allocatorIS6_EEEE + 884
10  libtorch_cpu.dylib                  0x00000001570a2a50 _ZN5torch8autograd4NodeclEONSt3__16vectorIN2at6TensorENS2_9allocatorIS5_EEEE + 120
11  libtorch_cpu.dylib                  0x000000015709983c _ZN5torch8autograd6Engine17evaluate_functionERNSt3__110shared_ptrINS0_9GraphTaskEEEPNS0_4NodeERNS0_11InputBufferERKNS3_INS0_10ReadyQueueEEE + 2932
12  libtorch_cpu.dylib                  0x00000001570986e0 _ZN5torch8autograd6Engine11thread_mainERKNSt3__110shared_ptrINS0_9GraphTaskEEE + 640
13  libtorch_cpu.dylib                  0x00000001570973c4 _ZN5torch8autograd6Engine11thread_initEiRKNSt3__110shared_ptrINS0_10ReadyQueueEEEb + 336
14  libtorch_python.dylib               0x000000014867df38 _ZN5torch8autograd6python12PythonEngine11thread_initEiRKNSt3__110shared_ptrINS0_10ReadyQueueEEEb + 112
15  libtorch_cpu.dylib                  0x00000001570a5bb0 *ZNSt3__1L14__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJNS_10unique_ptrINS_15__thread_structENS_14default_deleteIS3_EEEEMN5torch8autograd6EngineEFviRKNS_10shared_ptrINS8_10ReadyQueueEEEbEPS9_aSC_bEEEEEPvSJ* + 76
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b291e06c _pthread_start + 148
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b2918e2c thread_start + 8
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
[1]    8858 abort      /Users/dimitardimitrov/miniconda3/envs/pytorch2/bin/python
/Users/dimitardimitrov/miniconda3/envs/pytorch2/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:224: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '

```
This is my environment:

Here is my environment information:

Versions
PyTorch version: 2.0.0
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: None
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: macOS 13.0 (arm64)
GCC version: Could not collect
Clang version: 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
CMake version: Could not collect
Libc version: N/A

Python version: 3.10.10 (main, Mar 21 2023, 13:41:05) [Clang 14.0.6 ] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: macOS-13.0-arm64-arm-64bit
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: No CUDA
CUDA_MODULE_LOADING set to: N/A
GPU models and configuration: No CUDA
Nvidia driver version: No CUDA
cuDNN version: No CUDA
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A
Is XNNPACK available: True

CPU:
Apple M1 Pro

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] mypy-extensions==0.4.3
[pip3] numpy==1.23.5
[pip3] torch==2.0.0
[pip3] torchaudio==2.0.0
[pip3] torchsummary==1.5.1
[pip3] torchvision==0.15.0
[conda] numpy 1.23.5 py310hb93e574_0
[conda] numpy-base 1.23.5 py310haf87e8b_0
[conda] pytorch 2.0.0 py3.10_0 pytorch
[conda] torchaudio 2.0.0 py310_cpu pytorch
[conda] torchsummary 1.5.1 pypi_0 pypi
[conda] torchvision 0.15.0 py310_cpu pytorch



I tried running it with batch size 4 to make sure it is not a memory issue, as well as running it on cpu, which worked. I ran it with the full model frozen and full model trainable both worked. The only case when the error occurs is when only the batchnorm layers are frozen.
```